# My web services work only for System Administrator profile

Tags: apex, permissions, profile, webservices

I have an issue, **I have two web services callouts for the Account object**,

- Consults to a Datawarehouse if that account already exists
- Sends the data to a different system,

those services works perfect.

When an account is created, two notifications popups telling "*Hey, the client was inserted*" and "*Web services status: OK*", this works
perfect but only if I'm logged as System Administrator.

In my system there is several profiles with different roles, so there is Sales Role and Sales Profile type too. As an Admin, I could login as sales person and checking on that time the web services doesn't work.

> When an account is created, It must return a code from the datawarehouse,  it comes as empty and the notification doesn't popup either.

The problem isn't the Role, But it's in profile, if I change same user with the Role as Salesman, but profile as `System Administrator`,It's works as expected.

So I don't know if there is some type of permission I need to give to the Sales profile so the `Web Service` can work as expected.

Any helps appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: User that is using web service needs to have an access to Apex Class with a web service and all the data referenced/mentioned. That is a point to start checking. It is hard to give meaningful advice without seeing exact code, data and sharing settings.

Comment: But, wich part of the code could have relation with this issue? I thought would be like configuration setting

Comment: You need to configure the profile to have access to the apex class that implements the web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was solved by creating a permission sets, including in it permissions of all the fields used in the web services. Then this permission sets were assigned to the users that the web services did not work for.

Comment: You were very helpful xixatumare